# Voltage translator max frequency?

Tags: high-speed

I know this question depends on the component but let's take this one for example : https://www.nexperia.com/products/analog-logic-ics/asynchronous-interface-logic/voltage-translators-level-shifters/74AVCH1T45GW.html

How do you calculate the input signal max frequency ? I know it related to the propagation delay of the voltage translator but I don't get the same data rates as the ones described in the datasheet.

For example, I'd like to translate a 3.3V 100MHz clock to a 1.8V 100MHz clock. Is it a good solution ?

Comment: It's not related to the propagation delay.

Comment: The data sheet has a section explicitly for this, E.g. _500 Mbit/s (1.8 V to 3.3 V translation)_

Comment: Read section 2.